# python built-in function to do matrix reduction

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

Does python have a built-in function that converts a matrix into row echelon form (also known as upper triangular)?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you can use [`sympy`](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/), [`Matrix.rref()`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.Matrix.rref) can do it:

```
In [8]: sympy.Matrix(np.random.random((4,4))).rref()
Out[8]: 
([1, 1.42711055402454e-17, 0, -1.38777878078145e-17]
[0,                  1.0, 0,  2.22044604925031e-16]
[0, -2.3388341405089e-16, 1, -2.22044604925031e-16]
[0, 3.65674099486992e-17, 0,                   1.0],
 [0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: How to interpret the result?

Comment: The 4x4 matrix is your matrix in RRE (watch out for floating point precision), and the 1x4 matrix lists the indices of your pivot vars.

Comment: by hand, ~5-10 minutes. By sympy, 1.13 ms  :-3

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer.  It is not that straightforward to convert back to a numpy array, though.  I used `np.array(sympy.lambdify((),result[0])())`.  Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Never mind, `np.array(result[0].tolist(), dtype=float)` is simpler.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with a @Mile comment  [to @WinstonEwert answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7665269/1887559)  There's no reason a computer could not perform RREF with **given precision**.

The realization of RREF shouldn't be very complicated, and matlab somehow managed to have this function, so numpy should have too.

I did a very simple and straightforward realization, which is very inefficient. But for simple matrices it works pretty well:

**UPDATE:**

Seems, @JustMe spotted a bug in this `rref` realization, which appeared if an input matrix has the first column of zeros. So here an updated version.

```py
from numpy import *

def rref(mat,precision=0,GJ=False):
    m,n = mat.shape
    p,t = precision, 1e-1**precision
    A = around(mat.astype(float).copy(),decimals=p )
    if GJ:
        A = hstack((A,identity(n)))
    pcol = -1 #pivot colum
    for i in range(m):
        pcol += 1
        if pcol >= n : break
        #pivot index
        pid = argmax( abs(A[i:,pcol]) )
        #Row exchange
        A[i,:],A[pid+i,:] = A[pid+i,:].copy(),A[i,:].copy()
        #pivot with given precision
        while pcol < n and abs(A[i,pcol]) < t:
            pcol += 1
            if pcol >= n : break
            #pivot index
            pid = argmax( abs(A[i:,pcol]) )
            #Row exchange
            A[i,:],A[pid+i,:] = A[pid+i,:].copy(),A[i,:].copy()
        if pcol >= n : break
        pivot = float(A[i,pcol])
        for j in range(m):
            if j == i: continue
            mul = float(A[j,pcol])/pivot
            A[j,:] = around(A[j,:] - A[i,:]*mul,decimals=p)
        A[i,:] /= pivot
        A[i,:] = around(A[i,:],decimals=p)
        
    if GJ:
        return A[:,:n].copy(),A[:,n:].copy()
    else:
        return A
```

Here are some simple tests

```py
print("/*--------------------------------------/")
print("/             Simple TEST               /")
print("/--------------------------------------*/")
A = array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[-7,8,9]])
R = rref(A,precision=6)
print("A:\n",A)
print("R:\n",R)
print()
print("With GJ ")
R,E =   rref(A,precision=6,GJ=True)
print("R:\n",R)
print("E:\n",E)
print("AdotE:\n",around( dot(A,E), decimals=0))
print()
A = array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]) 
R = rref(A, precision=1)
print("A:\n",A)
print("R:\n",R)
print()
A = array([[1,2,2,2],[2,4,6,8],[3,6,8,10]])
R = rref(A,precision=6)
print("A:\n",A)
print("R:\n",around(R, decimals=0))
print()

print("/*--------------------------------------/")
print( "/        Not Invertable TEST            /")
print( "/--------------------------------------*/")
A = array([
    [2,2,4, 4],
    [3,1,6, 2],
    [5,3,10,6]])
R = rref(A,precision=2)
print("A:\n",A)
print("R:\n",R)
print()
print("A^{T}:\n",A.T)
R = rref(A.T,precision=10)
print("R:\n",R)
```

```
/*--------------------------------------/
/             Simple TEST               /
/--------------------------------------*/
A:
 [[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [-7  8  9]]
R:
 [[1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1.]]

With GJ 
R:
 [[1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1.]]
E:
 [[-0.071428  0.142857 -0.071429]
  [-1.857142  0.714285  0.142857]
  [ 1.595237 -0.523809 -0.071428]]
AdotE:
 [[ 1.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  1.  0.]
  [-0.  0.  1.]]

A:
 [[0 0 1]
  [0 1 0]]
R:
 [[0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1.]]

A:
 [[ 1  2  2  2]
  [ 2  4  6  8]
  [ 3  6  8 10]]
R:
 [[ 1.  2.  0. -2.]
  [ 0.  0.  1.  2.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]

/*--------------------------------------/
/        Not Invertable TEST            /
/--------------------------------------*/
A:
 [[ 2  2  4  4]
  [ 3  1  6  2]
  [ 5  3 10  6]]
R:
 [[ 1.  0.  2.  0.]
  [-0.  1. -0.  2.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]

A^{T}:
 [[ 2  3  5]
  [ 2  1  3]
  [ 4  6 10]
  [ 4  2  6]]
R:
 [[ 1.  0.  1.]
  [-0.  1.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: the line `pcol += 1` should be the first thing we do in the `while ...` loop for this implementation to work correctly.

Comment: @joni i cannot edit the answer ("too many pending edits"). If you agree with the correction, could you please fix it for future users' benefit?

Comment: I'm not. @JustMe could you please explane why?

Comment: it appears the intention was that when you exit the loop, `i, pcol` should point to the pivot element - the largest element in the lower portion of column `pcol`, brought up to the current row `i`. Then we should apply row operations *to the same column* to clear the elements below it. But as it is, we advance `pcol` to the next column.
If this isn't convincing, ```A = array([[0,0, 1], [0, 1, 0]])
print(rref(A, precision=5))```
gives 
```[[0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]]
```
which is not in row echelon form.

Comment: That said we should also add a check `if pcol >= n : break` inside the `while` loop after we advance `pcol`.

Answer (score 5):

see http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2008-November/038705.html

Basically: don't do it.

The rref algorithm produces too much inaccuracy when implemented on a computer. So you either want to solve the problem in another way, or use symbolics like @aix suggested.

Comment: Just wrap your numbers in a rational datatype such as python's `fraction.Fraction`, which is already overloaded for the arithmetic operations. You can even vectorize the constructor with numpy, ie `VecFraction = np.vectorize(fraction.Fraction)` and `rational_array = VecFraction(numeric_array)`. There's no reason a computer could not perform exact RREF.

Comment: The link in the answer doesn't work for me, http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Reduced-row-echelon-form-td16486.html

Comment: "or use symbolics like @aix suggested", where's this written?

Comment: If rref is inaccurate on a computer, then why do we have the similar algorithm LU implemented on scipy for production use?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. In `scipy.linalg`, `lu` does LU decomposition which will essentially get you row-echelon form.

There are other factorizations such as `qr`, `rq`, `svd`, and more, if you're interested.

[Documentation.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu.html)

Comment: LU decomposition is not the same as row-echelon form. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1614952

Comment: Yes, it is possible to compute the reduced row echelon from these functions but why make the user jump through the hoops. Most sensible applications such as scilab, Matlab, Mathematica etc, have these built-in. Instead, Python uses must go through the symbolic algebra library.

Comment: "*In scipy.linalg, lu does LU decomposition which will essentially get you row-echelon form*": Perhaps you can provide an example showing how to use the `p, l, u` matrices returned by `lu` to obtain the RRE form.

Answer (score 2):

You can define it yourself:

```
def rref(matrix):
    A = np.array(matrix, dtype=np.float64)

    i = 0 # row
    j = 0 # column
    while True:
        # find next nonzero column
        while all(A.T[j] == 0.0):
            j += 1
            # if reached the end, break
            if j == len(A[0]) - 1 : break
        # if a_ij == 0 find first row i_>=i with a 
        # nonzero entry in column j and swap rows i and i_
        if A[i][j] == 0:
            i_ = i
            while A[i_][j] == 0:
                i_ += 1
                # if reached the end, break
                if i_ == len(A) - 1 : break
            A[[i, i_]] = A[[i_, i]]
        # divide ith row a_ij to make it a_ij == 1
        A[i] = A[i] / A[i][j]
        # eliminate all other entries in the jth column by subtracting
        # multiples of of the ith row from the others
        for i_ in range(len(A)):
            if i_ != i:
                A[i_] = A[i_] - A[i] * A[i_][j] / A[i][j]
        # if reached the end, break
        if (i == len(A) - 1) or (j == len(A[0]) - 1): break
        # otherwise, we continue
        i += 1
        j += 1

    return A
```

Comment: There are a couple of mistakes with this, but I still find the process elegant:

1. if j == len(A[0]) - 1 should break out of the external while
2. you should check whether A[i][j] is not zero (and ideally not one), before normalizing
3. you should only multiply other rows if A[i][j] is not zero

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version that's pretty much just a numpy version of MATLAB's rref function:

```py
def rref(A, tol=1.0e-12):
    m, n = A.shape
    i, j = 0, 0
    jb = []

    while i < m and j < n:
        # Find value and index of largest element in the remainder of column j
        k = np.argmax(np.abs(A[i:m, j])) + i
        p = np.abs(A[k, j])
        if p <= tol:
            # The column is negligible, zero it out
            A[i:m, j] = 0.0
            j += 1
        else:
            # Remember the column index
            jb.append(j)
            if i != k:
                # Swap the i-th and k-th rows
                A[[i, k], j:n] = A[[k, i], j:n]
            # Divide the pivot row i by the pivot element A[i, j]
            A[i, j:n] = A[i, j:n] / A[i, j]
            # Subtract multiples of the pivot row from all the other rows
            for k in range(m):
                if k != i:
                    A[k, j:n] -= A[k, j] * A[i, j:n]
            i += 1
            j += 1
    # Finished
    return A, jb
```

Example:

```py
A = np.array([[16.0, 2, 3, 13], [5, 11, 10, 8],
              [9, 7, 6, 12], [4, 14, 15, 1]])
Areduced, jb = rref(A)
print(f"The matrix as rank {len(jb)}")
print(Areduced)
```

Comment: I tried this version, but it has some weird behavior with floating point given your example:

[[ 1.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  3.]
 [ 0.  0.  1. -3.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]

vs. int

[[1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]]