# Python reduced row echelon

Tags: python

How do you write a python function that turns a matrix into reduced row echelon form and does not swap rows.

I am not sure how to do this can anyone show me how?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

The following example code from the answer by @npe on stackoverflow may help you. I'm not sure if it will swap rows, but it should give you something to investigate..

```
If you can use sympy, Matrix.rref() can do it:

In [8]: sympy.Matrix(np.random.random((4,4))).rref()
Out[8]:   
([1, 1.42711055402454e-17, 0, -1.38777878078145e-17]
[0,                  1.0, 0,  2.22044604925031e-16]
[0, -2.3388341405089e-16, 1, -2.22044604925031e-16]
[0, 3.65674099486992e-17, 0,                   1.0],
[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Source of answer:
[python built-in function to do matrix reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664246/python-built-in-function-to-do-matrix-reduction)